# How do I convert a timestamp Series in to a Series of integer values without doing element by element conversion

Tags: python, loops

I wish to convert a Series of timestamp elements into their "value" integer equivalent. I implemented the code below which works but takes FOREVER with large Series. How do I implement to operate on the entire series instead of element by element?

" Build numeric timestamp vector "

```py
for i in range(0, rows):
    TimeDecVal[i] = (TimeEntry[i].value - DateTimeRefVal)/nanosec_ct
```

Comment: To convert them all, you need to convert them all, even if you don't have to explicitly write the loop.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: What is `DateTimeRefVal` and `nanosec_ct`? Looks like you should be able to simply use vectorization: `(TimeEntry.value - DatTimeRefVal) / nanosec_ct`

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a pandas.Series, try this:

```py
date_series.apply(datetime.timestamp).astype(int)
```

Should be much faster. (I tested a Series of 10,000,000 elements on colab and it took 1.05 seconds.)